# Kafka connect error while loading debezium - "Unable to instantiate " " Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster"

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I run zookeper, kafka, and debezium in my AWS server. I need to connect it with my local machine's mysql and fetch the data from mysql to debezium.

By runnig debezium connector i get these errors.

[2024-03-21 12:56:22,179] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli:100)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.

[2024-03-21 12:55:15,754] ERROR Failed to discover Converter in /home/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql: Unable to instantiate CloudEventsConverter: Failed to statically initialize plugin class (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.ReflectionScanner:138)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

How will i solve this issue?